# valid anagram with O(n) time and 1 extra space, not 256

Tags: algorithm

I tried to work out solution for validating anagram with O(n) time , 1 space.
I came up with bitwise approach.

anagram(s,t) to decide if two strings are anagrams or not.

Example

```
Given s = "abcd", t = "dcab", return true.  
Given s = "ab", t = "ab", return true.  
Given s = "ab", t = "ac", return false.
```

time: n , space 256
I've already had 256 space version.

```
    public boolean anagram(String s, String t) {

    if(s == null || t == null){
        return false;
    }
    if(s.length() != t.length()){
        return false;
    }

    int n = s.length();
    int[] count = new int[256];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        count[s.charAt(i)]++;
        count[t.charAt(i)]--;
    }

    for(int i : count){
        if(i != 0){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

My code with bitwise solution

It cannot pass this test case:

```
s: "az"  ,  t: "by"
```

I know my code is wrong, I want to find out O(n) time and 1 space solution, no sorting, it will take O(nlgn) time.

The code below is incorrect.

time: n , space 1

```
 public boolean anagram(String s, String t) {

    if(s == null || t == null || s.length() != t.length()){
        return false;
    }

    int n = s.length();
    int x = s.charAt(0) ^ t.charAt(0);

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        x ^= s.charAt(i);
        x ^= t.charAt(i);
    }

    return x == 0;
}
```

I'm trying to work out with just 1 extra space.
Maybe there is no way to work it out.

Comment: This algorithm is just wrong. It only tells you if a hash of the two strings is identical.

Comment: Bitwise can give same results for multiple strings. So, this is incorrect.

Comment: I know my code is wrong, I want to find out O(n) time and O(1) space solution, no sorting, it will take O(nlgn) time.

Comment: @landscape1250 please see Apoorva's answer for O(n) time O(1) space.

Comment: @landscape1250 I have added the code if you didn't get the concept.

Comment: You silently changed the title and the question, which is bad practice. And the notation O(1) does not mean at all that you allow only "1" extra space (which by the way is meaningless).

Comment: ok, I made mistake, sorry.

Comment: @landscape1250: you seem to be unaware of the O(N) sorting algorithms, and of the exact meaning of the Big-O notation.

Comment: do you mean bucket sort, does it take just 1 space. If I use java Arrays.sort, it wil take O(nlgn)

Comment: Is this a theoretical exercise or a real-life problem ?

Comment: actually not in real life, just want to figure out a bitwise way to distinguish strings

Comment: 256 is O(1). It isn't clear what is your objection to it.

Comment: @landscape1250 You need to understand that the space 256 solution that you have is already O(1). So when you say *"I want to find out O(n) time and O(1) space solution"*, you already have that solution (it's the 256 space solution). There is no 1 space solution that runs in O(n) time.

Comment: I think the confusion here is the meaning of "O(1) space." You should read that as "A constant amount of space." The point here is that 256 is constant; you use the same amount of extra space regardless of the string length.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean anagram(String s, String t) {

    if(s == null || t == null || s.length() != t.length()){
        return false;
    }

    int[] hash = new int[256];// all have 0 by default

    for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;--i){
        hash[(int)s.charAt(i)]++;
        hash[(int)t.charAt(i)]--;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<256;++i){
        if(hash[i] != 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

s: "az"  ,  t: "by"

x = a^b = 3;

then x = 3^z = 121;
then y = 121 ^ y = 0;  as the ascii value of y is 121.

I think the approach you have to compare words for anagram is not correct. Please revisit.

I would rather use an array with count for all the characters. If you know the string input is just limited to alphabets then use an array of size 26. But if the input could be any character then use the array of size 256.

This way the complexity will remain O(n)time and O(1) space.

Comment: If the strings are short, handling arrays of 256 can be too much.

Comment: It actually depends on the character set. Ideally for example with just alphabets array of size 26 is sufficient.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Single array of size 256 is perfectly fine. It's `O(1)` space.

Comment: @SomeDude Even that is also a better datastructure to use.

Comment: @SomeDude Using a HashMap will get slower in time I presume. Arrays are faster.

Comment: @vivek_23: strictly sticking to the O(N) requirement, yes, this is fine. In practice it may be overkill.

Comment: @vivek_23 with good hashing ( today's languages do have good hashing functions ) insert, update and read are O(1).

Comment: @vivek_23: a HashMap can get slower in time, until all characters have been seen, then it will stabilize. But hashing the character value to finally store in an array with much added overhead is nonsensical compared to direct array access.

Comment: @SomeDude Collisions will still occur although it is very negligible in OP's usecase.

Comment: @SomeDude: using a hashmap instead of an array is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you are right, as I think the hashtable implementation internally uses a large array to place the key in an appropriate position as returned by hashcode. So as might it appear that hashmap consumes only size of the order of number of keys, internal implementation actually does use a large array. Deleting my original comment.

Comment: @SomeDude: a hashmap will also add the cost of hashing the keys, and collision detection/resolution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I assume hashing characters is O(1), its just the int value of the character. And collision detection would never need to be done. If it needed to be done even for characters, then that language is useless.

Comment: @SomeDude: "collision detection would never need to be done": you don't know, that will depend on the particular hashing function. And a standard hashmap will perform it anyway. Even if hashing is O(1), this is unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to detect anagrams is to sort their letters and compare the sorted words for equality.

Given the (presumably) short length of the words and the short size of the alphabet, different options are possible (straight selection sort, straight insertion sort, mergesort, counting sort, radix sort, optimized for small sizes).

A possible micro-optimization is to perform both sorts in parallel and conclude as soon as there is a discrepancy between the partially sorted words.

Comment: sorting will take O(nlgn) time. I need O(n) with just O(1) space.

Comment: @landscape1250: counting sort is fine then.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Counting sort needs space of O(n + k ) where n is size of string and k is auxiliary space determined by range of input.

Comment: @SomeDude: k is a fixed constant (alphabet size), hence you wrote space O(n). Usually you don't count the input storage in the space requirement, so actually O(1) extra space.

Comment: Counting sort is rather silly. Once you're done counting, you have the answer, there's no reason to finish the sort.

Comment: @user3386109: I said counting sort for short, so that people know what I am talking about while listing different sorts.